# How to get current WordPress category in FishPig in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, fishpig

What is the most straightforward way to get the current category in the view? I notice that there is a getTerm method in the Term class:

```
public function getEntity()
{
    return $this->getTerm();
}

/**
 * Returns the current Wordpress category
 * This is just a wrapper for getCurrentCategory()
 *
 * @return \FishPig\WordPress\Model\Term
 */
public function getTerm()
{
    if (!$this->hasTerm()) {
        $this->setTerm($this->_registry->registry(Term::ENTITY));
    }

    return $this->_getData('term');
}
```

However if I try to utilize the method within a template (for example, the default post list wrapper.phtml template which utilizes the Term block in the layout) it throws an error:

```
<?php echo $this->getTerm() ?>
```

> Recoverable Error: Object of class FishPig\WordPress\Model\Term could
>   not be converted to string in

I'm probably just missing something simple, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$term = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
          ->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')
          ->registry('wordpress_term');
```

Comment: Thanks! And for anyone else who might be interested, just call `getName()` on the $term object to get the category name.